# Some users bypassing client side validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I'm trying to get to the bottom of how some of my websites users are bypassing client-side javascript form validation.  I have a multi-step form that will not work with javascript switched off as it's steps are shown / hidden as you progress, and the submit button works via ajax (ie it doesn't have the `type="submit"` attribute).

I'm using the [1000hz validator.js](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/) library to handle validation and from extensive testing I'm confident it works across all inputs on the form.

One of the fields on the form is a UK mobile phone number, so it should start 07 and be 11 numbers long.  I'm using a regular expression `pattern="^07\d{9}$"` for this check and it works just fine, in that I can't progress with the form unless the format is entered correctly.

From looking through the form submissions though I'm finding around 1% of applications with this field entered in an invalid format, for example 12 characters long or else with special characters, eg country code prepended `(+44)`

I don't think there's anything malicious going on, for example people attempting to post this data using a tool as it does look like valid traffic.

The user agents for these posts are all slightly different however a lot of them seem to come from Android 4.4.2, ie..

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; N830 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

I've tried to replicate this using a similar device but the validation appears to be working just fine.

Comment: There is no way to restrict user from hacking client side code. You should have extra check on server side for validation.

Comment: Yeh I know this, I have server side validation, these apps arent being accepted as the mobile number is invalid, it doesn't look like faked data is what I'm saying

Comment: Is the bypassing offering the user some kind of advantage? Do you think they are purposely hacking or could it be that they are unaware of it? Maybe they are using older browsers and your scripts have bugs on them?

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin: Mostly purposely. Browser wont edit attribute value on their own. However user can inspect element and make whatever changes they want. In current case, i believe user is modifying pattern attribute as a hack.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar I know what people are capable of doing, however I've ruled it out as the traffic looks valid.  We send out tracking cookies with our marketing and this has happened for various different email marketing transaction codes so it'd be extremely coincidental if this was malicious

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin no, no advantage is gained from submitting these applications maliciously, as I've said before, we've ruled this out, I'm just trying to come up with anything else to investigate.  The user agents seem to point to the traffic being from Android mobile devices however I'm using physical devices and also Browser Stack and cannot replicate the behaviour

Answer (score 0):

The library that is doing input validation is probably not loading. There could be various reasons for this:

1. The http request for the library fails - the end user might not be able to reach the domain where the library is at;
2. The end user has installed some third party plugin, such has an ad block plugin, which prevents the library from running;
3. There's a bug in the code that causes the library from compiling on a specific browser;
4. The end user is controlling which scripts he wishes to run;

You should switch to server side validation to prevent further errors from happening.

Comment: Last sentence is gold. Never ever trust what you get from the client. Always do server validation.

Comment: Yes always do server side validation but the sentence implies you should only do server side validation. You should have both, to a certain degree atleast,  client side validation done right enhances usability and reduce unneeded roundtrips to server.